# ec2, tomcat7 and 503 error

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have Amazon's out of the box instance with Tomcat7 (ami-518e4c38), deployed a war file to it, but keep getting 503 error.

I've set the connector to listen on port 80 in server.xml, in the default security group I got  80 (HTTP) set to 0.0.0.0/0

I'm assuming that I don't have to start/stop tomcat manually, should start when the instance is launched. Am I correct on this one?

When I ping localhost (while ssh'ed into the instance ) 2 times on port 80 I get:

```
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: why don't you check if tomcat is up with a "ps fax | grep tomcat" ?

Comment: ... hm, just did, this is what I got, so what am I looking here:  1127 pts/0    S+     0:00              \_ grep tomcat
  987 ?        Sl     0:42 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -classpath /opt/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat7 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat7/endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat7/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Comment: it means that it's running. do you have only a status 503, not a longer error message that you can copy and paste here?

Comment: @stivlo, if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriously, this isn't an answer, you should describe your initial situation and what you did in your answer and accept it.

I just want to clear up what happened, and I would need your feedback to understand more about it.

Initially you had a 503 error, which means **service unavailable**, normally Tomcat is configured behind Apache, and with this I mean that the Apache server gets (all) the requests and may forward (some of) them to Tomcat, if configured to do so.

If you get a 503 error, it means there is some server up and running to reply to you and that should be Apache. If I shut down Tomcat and try to request an URL that would be forwarded to Tomcat I get:

> **Service Temporarily Unavailable**
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
> Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at private.it Port 80

That's why my first thought was to check if Tomcat was running. Then you did:

```
$ ps fax | grep tomcat
```

And you got that tomcat was actually running:

> 1127 pts/0 S+ 0:00 _ grep tomcat 987 ? Sl 0:42 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -classpath /opt/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat7 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat7/endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat7/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Another reason could be that the connection Tomcat-Apache is not configured correctly. However then you posted that Tomcat was trying to bind port 80 and failing:

> Sep 30, 2011 4:07:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"] java.net.BindException: Address already in use :80

I tried to replicate that error, I went in my `conf/server.xml` file and change the connector to listen on port 80 instead of 8080:

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            connectionTimeout="20000" 
            redirectPort="8443" />
```

I start tomcat and monitor the log:

```
bin/startup.sh && tail -f logs/catalina.out
```

And I get an exception that is similar to what you get, but not exactly the same:

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:80
```

Now if I check whether Tomcat is running I find that is indeed running. While without checking I'd have supposed that in a case like that the server would have just gave up and quit. In my case the correction would be, either shut down Apache and use Tomcat directly, which is not advisable for high traffic sites or move Tomcat back to port 8080 and install mod_jk.

[The installation of mod_jk](http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=716) enables the communication between Apache and Tomcat. Then in the virtual host configuration I'd mount a folder or the root folder and do some URL rewriting if necessary:

```
JkMount /webappname/* ajp13_worker
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/nametoshow/(.*)$ /webappname/$1 [PT,QSA]
```

And everything should work. However, I am not sure how you solved the bind error, you didn't say.